Kotlin variable vs field initialization semantics
Let's consider the following Koltin code:
val a: Int = 1
class A {
    val a: Int = a   // error here: a is not initialized
    fun f() {
        val a = a    // this is fine, a on the right-hand side is resolved to the top-level a
    }
}

Why there is a difference between the way Kotlin initializes local variables and fields?
@tyg pointed out this question which somewhat answers the question: top-level variable may not be initialized at the moment of class initialization. But I think there is more to it.
Let's consider this example, which compiles fine.
class A {
    val a: Int = b // compiles fine
    companion object {
        val b: Int = 1
    }
}

However, if I change b to a, I get an error:
class A {
    val a: Int = a   // error: a is not initialized
    companion object {
        val a: Int = 1
    }
}


To me it seems like the variable resolution for the fields is like this: first put a on the lhs to the symbol table, and then lookup all the variables on the rhs. And it's different from the local variable resolution, regardless of what rhs variables are.

In short: top-level variables are not guaranteed to be initialized before classes.

Yes, it's similar ands answers the question, but overall seems very confusing language design to me. Thanks for pointing out the link.

Although wait, I think it's not fully answering the question, let me edit the question.

That's a different question that has nothing to do with top-level variables. You should ask a new one for this. Although this is easily explained: Kotlin first tries to access instance variables, then it tries to access the companion object.

I see, makes sense. So the resolution order is like this: first, local variables, then fields, and then companion objects.

This is the sort of thing that an IDE can help investigate.  E.g. in IntelliJ, you can click on an identifier and its other uses and definition will be highlighted where visible; and you can go to the definition (by IIRC Cmd+clicking, or there will be a popup menu entry for it).
